# String concatentation in Bash doesn't consider string before variable

Tags: bash, string-concatenation

I have problems inserting the variable `$UUID`, defined by `UUID=$(curl https://www.uuidgenerator.net/api/version4)` into a string (using Bash on a Mac).

For example, `echo '->"'$UUID'"<-'` results in `"<-280bf23e-1774-4041-aeb7-15c8db8e24ce`, and not, as expected, in `->"280bf23e-1774-4041-aeb7-15c8db8e24ce"<-`.

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `curl https://www.uuidgenerator.net/api/version4` contains a `\r` carriage return CR character that shifts the cursor position to the beginning of the line while printing. Remove it, for example with `tr -d '\r'`.

```
UUID=$(curl https://www.uuidgenerator.net/api/version4 | tr -d '\r')
```